# Can't start Curity on Big Sur even with libcrypto installed

Tags: curity

After upgrading to Big Sur, I can't start Curity anymore. When I tried upgrading to 5.4, I can't even start the installer. Is this a problem with Curity or the new macOS version? When I run either `idsvr` or `installer.sh`, I get this error:

```
installer.sh requires libcrypto 1.1 to run.
Please install it if it is not already, or add it to your LD_LIBRARY_PATH. Then, restart installer.sh.
```

Answer (score 0):

Curity actually works fine on Big Sur. When it starts, however, it's checking that its dependency, libcrypto, is present. This check may fail on Big Sur on any versions of Curity up to and including 5.4. To work around this problem, set the environment variable `SKIP_LIB_CRYPTO_CHECK` to some value. For example, you can do this:

`SKIP_LIB_CRYPTO_CHECK=1 installer.sh`

After you've run the installer, you'll need to start it this way:

`SKIP_LIB_CRYPTO_CHECK=1 idsvr`

You can make this permanent by saving this environment variable in your profile, or aliasing the `idsvr` command.